# How to find scheduling policy and active processes' priority?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, ps

I want to show something like this :

```
pid 2089's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 2089's current scheduling priority: 0
pid 2092's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 2092's current scheduling priority: 0
pid 2093's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 2093's current scheduling priority: 0
```

using `awk` `chrt` and `ps` commands any ideas?

Comment: *any ideas?* - any efforts made by you?

Comment: well i can show this for a specific process for example for the process 1780 with chrt -p 1780 it shows :                                                                          
pid 1780's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 1780's current scheduling priority: 0                                                                               but i want this for every active process

Answer (score 0):

```
(cd /proc;echo [0-9]*)|xargs -n1 chrt -p
```

Comment: this is working perfectly thanks but do u know how i can only show only these who run?